# How to maintain information in a model state till user clicks submit and save to DB

Tags: go, go-echo

I have a UI where the user enters some information and upload files/ delete files and modify information in multiple steps. I want to store the information in an object model in Go and only send it to DB once the user clicks on the submit at the final step. please let me know, what would be the best approach to maintain the data. I am currently using the Echo web framework for the API.

Comment: Echo's [Session Middleware](https://echo.labstack.com/middleware/session) is a good starting point for solving this problem.

Comment: Why not record all the data operations on the client and send them all together to the server only once, when the user hits submit?

Comment: @mkopriva thanks for the suggestion. this is definitely one of the options, but the user wants to have a file upload progress for each file they upload/ drag and drop. which is possible only making a server call with XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: @CeriseLimón thanks for the suggestion, I will explore it more.